# setText(...) Not working when the form is visible

Tags: java, append, jtextarea, jdialog, settext

I have a problem : when I use the method "setText(...)" (or "append(...)") from JTextArea (or JTextPane), it does not work. I have no error in my console. Here is the code I use :

```
public class ConsoleFrame extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final JTextArea output = new JTextArea();

    public ConsoleFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Console");
        this.setSize(500, 376);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final Container content = this.getContentPane();
        output.setLineWrap(true);
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setText("Test 1");
        content.add(new JScrollPane(output), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
        output.setText(System.lineSeparator() + "Test 2");
        System.out.println(output.getText()); // Outputs "Test 1 Test 2";
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Strange, when I run your code, it displays "Test 1" in the console, then when I close your dialog it prints "{newline}Test 2" in the terminal. Everything is working as "expected". Could you detail what your issue is? Just remember that on a modal dialog, `setVisible(true)` is a blocking call.

Comment: Maybe if I remove the modality ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I am havinh a hard time understand what your final objective is. Explaining that would likely help us into helping you

Comment: Making a console but I solved my problem by changing the JDialog to JFrame.

Comment: I still don't know what you were trying to do nor what the problem was. Glad you got things working.

Answer (score -1):

After setVisible, any operations on the swing gui MUST happen in the Event Dispatching Thread. Otherwise you are in serious trouble.

Comment: That's not an answer, it barely qualifies as a comment and hardly shows relevance to the post

Comment: OK, you got the point - I missed the setModal(true) call. You should've posted your comment to the question as a solution ;-)